# Ghost story book with giant cats coming to life from the bedroom wallpaper

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ghost

This was a book of ghost stories from the late 80s.

- One story included giant cats coming to life from the bedroom wallpaper.
- Another story was of a ghost sat in armchair.
- Another was of a haunted portrait, I think.

Comment: If you could, visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to find some other possible details to add to your question. Was the book in English? Paperback or hardback? Did it have illustrations? If so, did they look like cartoons? Pen and ink? Penciled? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[Ghost Stories from North of England](https://mysterioustimes.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/review-ghost-stories-from-the-north-of-england-edited-by-george-white/)*, edited by George White? "The Cats of Keld" involves a writer being harassed by the ghostly feral cats of the prior owner of the cottage, and it looks like they reference the [Busby's stoop chair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busby%27s_stoop_chair), long alleged to be haunted and/or cursed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these stories were from the ***[St Michael Ghost Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/48758134-st-michael-ghost-stories)*** (1982) book. I had it in the 80s and found this thread by doing a similar search.

From Goodreads:

> Twenty Two spine-chilling tales from the masters of the genre. Authours include Edgar Allan Poe, Sheridan Le Fanu, M.R. James, Algernon Blackwood, Lovecraft, and many more.
>
> Featuring original illustrations to accompany each tale of the macabre.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Is this the book you're talking about? https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/48758134-st-michael-ghost-stories  Could you include some details about the specific stories?